# What's the function of finding list member index in this work flow?

Tags: indexing

I am following a free online course from University of Helsinki. It is "[Geo-Python 2019](https://geo-python.github.io/site/index.html)".
I'm using MacBook Pro, OS 10.14.x, and using Python 3.
The curriculum uses JupyterLab, but I am not using it because I cannot get it to work for me. I am simply using the terminal window and typing code as directed.
In [Exercise 2](https://github.com/geo-python-2019/Exercise-2/blob/master/Exercise-2.ipynb), there is this set of code in Jupyter Lab cells, which I am copying and running via my terminal:
station_names = ['Harmaja', 'Kaisaniemi', 'Kaivopuisto', 'Kumpula', 'lighthouse', 
'Malmi airfield', 'Suomenlinna aaltopoiju', 'Vuosaari harbour']
station_start_years = [1989, 1844, 1904, 2005, 2003, 1937, 2016, 2012]
selected_station = **whichever of the station names I select**
#The instructions say "Next we find the location of the selected station in the list of station names:"
station_index = station_names.index(selected_station)
#Instructions say "Now we can calculate the years the station has been operational:"
station_years = 2023 - station_start_years[selected_station]

My question is this: what is the purpose of finding the station name index? I don't see any code using that index for any purpose. I would think that one would use the station name index in the "station_years" line, to call up the relevant station name.

The code above is for their Problem 1. I copied and ran the code and it worked OK.
This question came up in trying to complete Problem 2 of the same exercise. That problem asks students to "...write some Python code that allows users to select a month and have the monthly average temperature printed to the screen."
It ought to be simple; there are only two lists (the months, and the average temperature for each month). I can do that. Then, the instructions say, I should enter and run
selected_month_index =
and the challenge is to complete that "selected_month_index" line properly.

I am not asking how to use index to find a list member. I am asking how the selected_month_index (or, in Problem 1, the selected_station_index) comes into play - how it is incorporated into the functioning of the code.